why i cannot login with new registered users in django while i can login with previous users
In Django, I create a user, then click the activation link to activate the account, after it is activated, I cannot login, I get DoesNotExist at / error
class VerificationView(View):
    def get(self, request, uidb64, token):
        try:
            # ! fixed force_text to force_str as it has been removed from later Django Versions
            id = force_str(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
            user = User.objects.get(pk=id)

            if not token_generator.check_token(user, token):
                return redirect("login"+"?message"+"User already activated")

            if user.is_active:
                return redirect("login")
            user.is_active = True
            user.save()

            messages.success(request, "Account activated successfully")
            return redirect("login")

        except Exception as ex:
            pass
        return redirect("login")


class LoginView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, "authentication/login.html")

    def post(self, request):
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]

        if username and password:
            user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user:
                if user.is_active:
                    auth.login(request, user)
                    messages.success(
                        request, "Welcome, "+user.username+" you are now logged in to your account")
                    return redirect("expenses")
                else:
                    messages.error(
                        request, "Account is not active, please check your email!")
                    return render(request, "authentication/login.html")
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid credentials, try again")
                return render(request, "authentication/login.html")
        else:
            messages.error(
                request, "Please provide both username and password.")
            return render(request, "authentication/login.html")

With previous logins all is fine, only new registered users are getting this error.

Share the full error traceback and that too as text.

Show us your custom auth backend. Do you use default user model or custom? Show us registration view code.

Please provide full traceback if possible.
